# What is this design style called in which lots of simple polygons make up an image?

Tags: style, style-identification

What is the design style called where they create form with simple shapes, usually triangles like they have done with the ground in the [Chrome Maze Experiment](http://chrome.com/maze/)

Or like the images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Im not sure who to mark as the correct answer  for @winnyboy5  more accurate results appear in google images
but it doesnt seem to really be a style.

Comment: http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

Comment: It's called "overly trendy"

Answer (score 6):

While we could trace the aesthetic back to various art and design styles such as the aforementioned cubism, there are some more recent terms such as **low-poly** or **faceted illustration**. [Tim Reynolds was one of the earlier users of the style.](http://www.turnislefthome.com/206637/2156611/3d-work-fun/low-poly-animal-kingdom)

It can be done via 3D rendering (where it originates...essentially reducing the polygons used to render a complex object), or 2D filters (or just by hand). There's an App for it too: [Dmesh](http://dmesh.thedofl.com/)

Related to it would be **voxel** style which, instead of connected planes to create a 3D shape, is used individual 3d shapes (such as in Minecraft).

Answer (score 6):

These are offshoots of [Delaunay Triangulation](http://jonathanpuckey.com/projects/delaunay-raster/) and can most easily be found by searching for "Delaunay Illustration", "Triangulated Illustrations" or "Triangulation Illustrations"

There are other tools that have since become available such as, [DMesh](http://www.creativeapplications.net/mac/dmesh-cinder-mac/).

Answer (score 5):

I call them **origami illustrations**.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Wild guesses aren't very useful, and most books seem to use "origami illustration" to describe the diagrams that tell you how to fold an illustration?

Comment: Interesting how many similar results appear on a [Google image search](https://www.google.co.nz/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHFX_enNZ516NZ516&espv=210&es_sm=93&biw=1093&bih=643&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=origami+illustrations&oq=origami+illustrations&gs_l=img.12...0.0.0.4521.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..36.img..0.0.0.ZPSSgEzlKZE) for those terms

Answer (score 5):

[Cubism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubism)

> Cubism is an early-20th-century avant-garde art movement pioneered by Georges Braque and Pablo Picasso, joined by Jean Metzinger, Albert Gleizes, Robert Delaunay, Henri Le Fauconnier, Fernand Léger and Juan Gris[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubism) that revolutionized European painting and sculpture, and inspired related movements in music, literature and architecture. Cubism has been considered the most influential art movement of the 20th century.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeMt6.jpg) The term is broadly used in association with a wide variety of art produced in Paris (Montmartre, Montparnasse and Puteaux) during the 1910s and extending through the 1920s. Variants such as Futurism and Constructivism developed in other countries.

---

Pablo Picasso paintings.....
[image: cubism]

Comment: yes and no :) Visually I feel you are correct. But cubism has this concept of merging objects and surrounding into one. So the geometric aspect can be used as inspiration but the style shown is certainly more of a "polygonal" one. Searching for "polygonal design" certainly turns up results like the one in the question.

Comment: It's all based upon Cubism - The notion of using geometric shapes to form an image.

Comment: Of course it's based on cubism. But I just would not have called it that as it is just different and only based on it.

Comment: Also just to mention; 'Cubism abandoned traditional perspective endeavouring to explore the multidimensional facets of an object rather than express it in a flat two dimensional manner. The elimination of colour and the application of collage emphasized the 'idea' of the object' - taken from The Thames and Hudson Dictionary of Graphic Design and Designers. By that measure I would be inclined to agree that the style above is definitely influenced by cubism, if not a modern form.

Comment: "Vector cubism" seems like a good description that gives a few [slightly similar results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vector+cubism%22&espv=210&es_sm=91&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=5woXU-3OEsWAhAfGo4DoCg&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=964&bih=640)

Answer (score 5):

The style is "cubist" or "cubism"

but I think the images you post have a definite digital feel.

I would call them "cubist illustration" or "digital cubism" if I were trying to specify and illustration style.

Comment: Thanks @pixelfairy - yeah your right my images do tend to have a more digital style