# What is this style of graphic called and is there any guide for how to create it

Tags: patterns

You see this style of graphic usually as a background in a banner or similar.

I'm interested to know if anyone know if there's an established term for graphics in this style (like "irregular matrix" or who knows), and also if you know how to create them fairly easily (preferably using Sketch 3, but CC tools would do as well).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **polygonal pattern**

There's  question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31727/how-can-i-create-a-polygon-pattern-in-photoshop) and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/how-do-i-create-a-polygon-tessellation-pattern-in-adobe-illustrator) with some details on the best way to make it.

There are also lots of resources to be found when searching for a polygonal pattern, free backgrounds, tutorials etc.

Hope I've helped :)

Comment: Hi Jenna, thanks for the tips! And thanks for letting me know what the correct term is. Polygonal patterns, I'll make sure to remember that! :)

Comment: Check this out: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/flat-surface-shader/